# Merging branches from the same trunk into one of the branches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

The drawing below shows what we have (RGB) and what we want to have (Purple).

[image]

On different time, we made three branches from trunk (features A to C). We already updated (merged) changes from trunk to each branch.

We could merge each branch into `trunk`, **however, we want to merge branch B and C into A**, and keep developing on branch A.

Is this possible, since branch B and C were not created from A but from `trunk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a 2-URL merge, as the text from `svn help merge` explains:

> 3. This form is called a '2-URL merge':
>
>    `svn merge SOURCE1[@REV1] SOURCE2[@REV2] [TARGET_WCPATH]`
>
>    You should use this merge variant only if the other variants do not
>      apply to your situation, as this variant can be quite complex to
>      master.
>
>    Two source URLs are specified, identifying two trees on the same
>      branch or on different branches. The trees are compared and the
>      difference from SOURCE1@REV1 to SOURCE2@REV2 is applied to the
>      working copy of the target branch at TARGET_WCPATH. The target
>      branch may be the same as one or both sources, or different again.
>      The three branches involved can be completely unrelated.
>
>    [...]
>
>    2-URL Merge Example:
>
>    Two features have been developed on separate branches called 'foo' and
>      'bar'. It has since become clear that 'bar' should be combined with
>      the 'foo' branch for further development before reintegration.
>
>    **Although both feature branches originate from trunk, they are not
>      directly related -- one is not a direct copy of the other. A 2-URL
>      merge is necessary.**

You say each branch has had all changes from *trunk* merged into it, so there should be no need to specify a revision for the first source.

First have a clean checkout of your *A* branch.  Then, merge *B* to *A*:

```
svn merge ^/trunk ^/branches/B
```

This will merge the differences between *B* and *trunk* into your working copy, which is *A*.  Verify and commit those changes (you can preview the merge by substituting `diff` for `merge` in the above command):

```
svn commit -m "Merging B to A"
```

Next, merge *C* to *A*:

```
svn merge ^/trunk ^/branches/C
```

This will merge the differences between *C* and *trunk* into your working copy, which is *A* with *B*'s changes.  Verify and commit those changes, and now your *A* branch will have all of *B*'s and *C*'s changes.

---

To verify this I created a simple script (Windows batch file).  It starts by setting some path constants:

```vb
@ECHO OFF

SET CWD=%~dp0
SET REPO_NAME=repo
SET REPO_PATH="%CWD%%REPO_NAME%"
SET WC_NAME=wc
SET WC_PATH="%CWD%%WC_NAME%"

:: Create REPO URI (C:\path\to\repo -> file:///C:/path/to/repo, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27817626/1698557)
FOR /f "delims=" %%R IN (%REPO_PATH%) DO SET REPO_URL=%%~fR%
SET REPO_URL=file:///%REPO_URL%
SET REPO_URL=%REPO_URL:///\\=//%
SET REPO_URL=%REPO_URL:\=/%
SET REPO_URL="%REPO_URL%"

:: Cleanup previous run
RMDIR /S /Q %REPO_PATH%
RMDIR /S /Q %WC_PATH%
```

Then create a repository and checkout trunk:

```vb
svnadmin create %REPO_PATH%
svn mkdir %REPO_URL%/trunk -m "Creating trunk directory"
svn mkdir %REPO_URL%/branches -m "Creating branches directory"

:: Checkout trunk
svn checkout %REPO_URL%/trunk %WC_PATH%
```

Alternate between creating dummy content and branches so the branches have different contents:

```vb
echo alpha > %WC_PATH%\alpha.txt
svn add %WC_PATH%\alpha.txt
svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Creating alpha.txt in trunk"
svn copy %REPO_URL%/trunk %REPO_URL%/branches/A -m "Creating branch A"

echo beta > %WC_PATH%\beta.txt
svn add %WC_PATH%\beta.txt
svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Creating beta.txt in trunk"
svn copy %REPO_URL%/trunk %REPO_URL%/branches/B -m "Creating branch B"

echo gamma > %WC_PATH%\gamma.txt
svn add %WC_PATH%\gamma.txt
svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Creating gamma.txt in trunk"
svn copy %REPO_URL%/trunk %REPO_URL%/branches/C -m "Creating branch C"

echo delta > %WC_PATH%\delta.txt
svn add %WC_PATH%\delta.txt
svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Creating delta.txt in trunk"
```

Now synchronize the branches by merging from trunk:

```vb
svn switch %REPO_URL%/branches/A %WC_PATH%
svn merge %REPO_URL%/trunk %WC_PATH%
svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Synchronizing branch A with trunk"

svn switch %REPO_URL%/branches/B %WC_PATH%
svn merge %REPO_URL%/trunk %WC_PATH%
svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Synchronizing branch B with trunk"

svn switch %REPO_URL%/branches/C %WC_PATH%
svn merge %REPO_URL%/trunk %WC_PATH%
svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Synchronizing branch C with trunk"
```

Create some different content in branches *B* and *C* so a merge will actually do something:

```vb
svn switch %REPO_URL%/branches/B %WC_PATH%
echo epsilon > %WC_PATH%\epsilon.txt
svn add %WC_PATH%\epsilon.txt
svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Creating epsilon.txt in B"

svn switch %REPO_URL%/branches/C %WC_PATH%
echo zeta > %WC_PATH%\zeta.txt
svn add %WC_PATH%\zeta.txt
svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Creating zeta.txt in C"
```

Switch our working copy back to branch *A*:

```vb
> svn switch %REPO_URL%/branches/A %WC_PATH%
D    wc\zeta.txt
 U   wc
Updated to revision 14.
```

Now, we're ready for our merge of *B* onto *A*:

```vb
> svn merge %REPO_URL%/trunk %REPO_URL%/branches/B %WC_PATH%
--- Merging differences between repository URLs into 'wc':
A    wc\epsilon.txt
 G   wc
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge between repository URLs into 'wc':
 G   wc
Sending        wc
Adding         wc\epsilon.txt

> svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Merged B to A"
Committing transaction...
Committed revision 15.

> svn update %WC_PATH%
Updating 'wc':
At revision 15.
```

So now *epsilon.txt* is in our *A* branch.  Let's now merge *C* onto *A*:

```vb
> svn merge %REPO_URL%/trunk %REPO_URL%/branches/C %WC_PATH%
--- Merging differences between repository URLs into 'wc':
A    wc\zeta.txt
 G   wc
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge between repository URLs into 'wc':
 G   wc
Sending        wc
Adding         wc\zeta.txt

> svn commit %WC_PATH% -m "Merged C to A"
Committing transaction...
Committed revision 16.

> svn update %WC_PATH%
Updating 'wc':
At revision 16.
```

This merged *zeta.txt* into *A*, and we can verify that if we look at *A* now:

```vb
> svn ls %REPO_URL%/branches/A
alpha.txt
beta.txt
delta.txt
epsilon.txt
gamma.txt
zeta.txt
```